# What methods can be used to kosher meat besides salting and roasting?

Tags: kashering-kosherization

There are several people I know that are on a strict no-salt diet. The only method to make meat and chicken kosher without salting that I know of is roasting.

This method is limiting. Not everyone wants roasted meat, and some meat cuts are not designed for roasting. What other methods (if there are any) can be used to make meat kosher? This would apply to meat as well as poultry.

(A few people have told me that even if you soak and rinse the salted meat a long time, there is still no way to eliminate **all** the salt. I can't verify this, myself, as salt is not a major concern for me.)